# how to upload a file into the WIKI of GitLab using Python

Tags: python, file-upload, gitlab, wiki

Using the Python module [python-gitlab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab), project management can be done on a GitLab server without using the built-in GitLab WEB-GUI, directly. So, the git repository and wikis can programmatically be operated on.

Now, I have found a way to download, edit and upload wiki pages by using this code:

```
# connect to GitLab server
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(
    <URL>,
    private_token=<TOKEN>,
    api_version=4,
    ssl_verify=False
)

# get list of owned projects
lstProjects_owned = gl.projects.list(owned=True)

lstProjectNames_owned = []
for i in range(0, len(lstProjects_owned)):
    lstProjectNames_owned.append(lstProjects_owned[i].name)

# get wiki page
idxProject = 0
slgWiki = 'home'
WikiPage = lstProjects_owned[idxProject].wikis.get(slgWiki)
```

But I have not found out (after reading various docs), how to upload a file which I can access by hyperlink from within a wiki page.

Does anybody know how to do this (preferrably with Python an the python-gitlab module)?

Comment: what happens when you upload a file normally to the wiki through the web gui? Where does it put it?

Comment: Hi @ritlew . Here is a markdown formatted link copied from the wiki page content: `[versions.txt](/uploads/fcb7dd5fd8e867d28d359e41f8d125c8/versions.txt)` . To me it seems as if there is an internal folder (not even accessible for delete of uploaded files), where files are uploaded permanently. The link is inserted automatically into the wiki page after upload via button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I have found:

You should use the gitlab api to interface with the project's *wiki repository* and upload the file that way. Look at how you can [clone the wiki repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/wiki/index.html#adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally) and also how to [upload a file](http://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html#id7). Check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228508/where-can-i-manage-files-uploaded-to-wiki-of-a-gitlab-com-project) for more information about the location to upload the file.

Then, simply [edit the wiki page](http://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/wikis.html#wiki-pages) with the hyperlink to the uploaded file using the wiki APIs which you are already using in your example.

I do not use gitlab, or this API, but these links should get you started on solving your problem.

Comment: unfortunately, the provided links show how to upload files **into the repository** . But, as wiki pages don't seem to be located there (they even have a separate change history), I see no possibility to upload files **into the wiki's upload folder** using the API. Of course, I could upload a file into the repository, but then I would guess that wiki readers (not allowed to see the repository's content) would not see the uploaded files when clicking the link from within the wiki page.

Comment: wikis are a separate repository according to the documentation

Comment: the hint with the [other forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228508/where-can-i-manage-files-uploaded-to-wiki-of-a-gitlab-com-project) helped me. the **solution** is to check out the wiki repo, create attachments within this repo and add respective file links into the wiki page. Then commit. Works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Upload attachement to Wiki" feature does not supported yet.
But we can use http_post() methods as a [workaround](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/issues/2258#issuecomment-1227222476).

Workable example is [here](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/issues/2258#issuecomment-1227518254)

```
filename = "myfile.png"
with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        filedata = f.read()
   url = "/projects/%d/wikis/attachments"%prj_id 
    file_info = {"file": (filename, filedata)}
    ans = gl.http_post(url, files=file_info)

    if 'link' in ans and 'markdown' in ans['link']:
        daily = daily + "\n" + ans['link']['markdown']
```